# Running total of Open Jobs reference Historical Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, trending

I tried searching but wasn't able to find exactly what I needed.  The issue is trying to calculate the running total of open jobs (status = open) and have that trended over time.  The big issue is needing to use a historical table to determine if a job was 'Open' based on the date in the graph.  I was able to put together something that works but only takes into account what the current status is.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIikP.png)  I can't figure out how to incorporate the historical data to grab if the job was open in a previous week using the historical table [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIGLj.png).  In this example, the job was on hold from 11/29/2022 to 1/17/2023 and at that point was open again and needing to be counted in the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.